# Python: subplots with different total sizes

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

### Original Post

I need to make several subplots with different sizes.

I have simulation areas of the size (x y) `35x6µm` to `39x2µm` and I want to plot them in one figure. All subplots have the same `x-ticklabels` (there is a grid line every `5µm` on the x-axis).

When I plot the subplots into one figure, then the graphs with the small x-area are streched, so that the `x-figuresize` is completely used. Therefore, the x-gridlines do not match together anymore.

How can I achieve that the subplots aren't streched anymore and are aligned on the left?

Edit: Here is some code:

```
    size=array([[3983,229],[3933,350],[3854,454],[3750,533],[3500,600]], dtype=np.float)
    resolution=array([[1024,256],[1024,320],[1024,448],[1024,512],[1024,640]], dtype=np.float)

    aspect_ratios=(resolution[:,0]/resolution[:,1])*(size[:,1]/size[:,0])

    number_of_graphs=len(data)
    fig, ax=plt.subplots(nrows=number_of_graphs, sharex=xshare)
    fig.set_size_inches(12,figheight)

    for i in range(number_of_graphs):
        temp=np.rot90(np.loadtxt(path+'/'+data[i])) 
        img=ax[i].imshow(temp, 
                 interpolation="none",
                 cmap=mapping, 
                 norm=specific_norm,
                 aspect=aspect_ratios[i]
                 )
        ax[i].set_adjustable('box-forced')

        #Here I have to set some ticks and labels....
        ax[i].xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(0,int(size[i,0]),stepwidth_width)*resolution[i,0]/size[i,0])
        ax[i].set_xticklabels((np.arange(0, int(size[i,0]), stepwidth_width)))
        ax[i].yaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(0,int(size[i,1]),stepwidth_height)*resolution[i,1]/size[i,1])
        ax[i].set_yticklabels((np.arange(0, int(size[i,1]), stepwidth_height)))
        ax[i].set_title(str(mag[i]))
        grid(True)


    savefig(path+'/'+name+'all.pdf', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.05) #saves graph
```

Here are some examples:
If I plot different matrices in a for loop, the iPhython generates an output which is pretty much what I want. The y-distande between each subplot is constant, and the size of each figure is correct. You can see, that the x-labels match to each other:
[image]

When I plot the matrices in one figure using subplots, then this is not the case: The x-ticks do not fit together, and every subplot has the same size on the canvas (which means, that for thin subplots there is more white space reservated on the canvas...).
[image]

I simply want the first result from iPython in one output file using subplots.

### Using GridSpec

After the community told me to use GridSpec to determine the size of my subplots directly I wrote a code for automatic plotting:

```
size=array([[3983,229],[3933,350],[3854,454],[3750,533],[3500,600]], dtype=np.float)

#total size of the figure
total_height=int(sum(size[:,1]))
total_width=int(size.max())

#determines steps of ticks
stepwidth_width=500
stepwidth_height=200


fig, ax=plt.subplots(nrows=len(size))
fig.set_size_inches(size.max()/300., total_height/200)

gs = GridSpec(total_height, total_width)
gs.update(left=0, right=0.91, hspace=0.2)

height=0
for i in range (len(size)):    
    ax[i] = plt.subplot(gs[int(height):int(height+size[i,1]), 0:int(size[i,0])])

    temp=np.rot90(np.loadtxt(path+'/'+FFTs[i])) 
    img=ax[i].imshow(temp, 
             interpolation="none", 
             vmin=-100,
             vmax=+100,
             aspect=aspect_ratios[i],
             )

    #Some rescaling            
    ax[i].xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(0,int(size[i,0]),stepwidth_width)*resolution[i,0]/size[i,0])
    ax[i].set_xticklabels((np.arange(0, int(size[i,0]), stepwidth_width)))
    ax[i].yaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(0,int(size[i,1]),stepwidth_height)*resolution[i,1]/size[i,1])
    ax[i].set_yticklabels((np.arange(0, int(size[i,1]), stepwidth_height)))
    ax[i].axvline(antenna[i]) #at the antenna position a vertical line is plotted
    grid(True)

    #colorbar
    cbaxes = fig.add_axes([0.93, 0.2, 0.01, 0.6])  #[left, bottom, width, height]
    cbar = plt.colorbar(img, cax = cbaxes, orientation='vertical')  
    tick_locator = ticker.MaxNLocator(nbins=3)
    cbar.locator = tick_locator
    cbar.ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.ticker.AutoLocator())
    cbar.set_label('Intensity', 
               #fontsize=12
               )
    cbar.update_ticks()

    height=height+size[i,1]


plt.show()
```

And here is the result....
[image]
Do you have any ideas?

Comment: show us some code, shall you?

Answer (score 2):

What about using `matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec`? [Docs](http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html).

You could try something like

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

gs = GridSpec(8, 39)
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[:6, :35])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[6:, :])

data1 = np.random.rand(6, 35)
data2 = np.random.rand(2, 39)

ax1.imshow(data1)
ax2.imshow(data2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. GridSpec is very useful! I've edited my entry post with a problem which occurs when I use gridspec....